# Angular not reading $rootScope variable during $locationChange

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes

I've set a login variable using `$rootScope` so my code knows if a user is logged in or not:

```
$rootScope.login = true;
```

Now, I want to redirect any location changes to the login page if the user is not logged in. So I tried this:

```
$scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(){   
  if (!$rootScope.login) $location.path('/');
});
```

But in this case, `$rootScope.login` returns undefined. If I try to print the variable to the page like so `{{login}}` it indeed shows true, so I know the variable is being set. What have I done wrong in my location change?

Comment: How are you updating login to true, is that any way happens during an async call. Can you show more relevant code. especially how you are setting the login property?

Comment: @PSL Ah yes I think you're right, I'm trying to read the variable before an async call sets it in the first place! Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

The preferred method for setting up user/login within angular is to set access from within your routes:

```
$routeProvider.when('/login', { 
    templateUrl: 'partials/main.html',
    controller: 'loginCtrl',
    access: {
        isloggedIn: true
    }
});
```

You can set the value `$scope.login` just as you were previously.

```
$root.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(event, currRoute, prevRoute){
    if ( !prevRoute.access.isLoggedIn && !$scope.login )  {
         console.log('user is not logged in');
    }
```